# creating block polygons on map using Pandas dataset

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly, geopandas

I have a dataset that includes the lat/longitude of different buildings in Detroit. I also have a column named unique_id that classifies each building and its neighbors to a ID, basically a block id, but named unique_id. I have calculated the average income of the people living in each unique_id and want to visualize this on a map such that there are different polygons that represent different unique_id and color code the plot with average_income.

this is the image I have right now, you can see I colored-coded them based on unique_id. I wonder if there's any way, preferably in Plotly, that I can connect the scattered points in the same unique_id to a polygon and color-code the polygon based on certain attributes

[image]

the pandas dataframe I have right now looks like this:

```
row#.       unique_id.     latitude.  longitude     average_income

0.               238.         111.       222.           1200
1.               239.         198.       350.           2200
2.               238.         112.       223.           1200
3.               238.         115.       222.           1200
```

In the example above, I would want to draw a polygon for the data in the row #0,2,3.

Thanks

Any help or suggestion are greatly appreciated!

Comment: you mean `row #0,2,3`, not `column #0,2,3.`

Comment: yea sorry, I just updated that

Comment: On the plotly map, [here](https://plotly.com/python/filled-area-on-mapbox/) are some examples so you can see what you're looking for.

Comment: if you want a polygon, it could be effectively a bounding polygon of all lat/lons within a set.  This can be achieved with **geopandas**. your example will not create polygons as there are not enough points (1 or 2 points does not make a polygon...). this would then be simple to plot on a plotly mapbox.  more representative data available through a GitHub link and I could demonstrate...